# Is there a way to increase a character's STATs with improvement points?

Tags: character-advancement, cyberpunk-red

I've just been checking the new *Cyberpunk RED* rules. The improvement points section (page 411) describes how your character skills (normal and x2) and your Role Ability Rank can be improved. However, since you are limited to a maximum of 8 in your starting STATs (INT, REF, DEX...) I supposed that it would list a cost for raising your base STATs as well, but can't find any mention of such a thing.

I don't know if I just missed something, or if it's only intended to be able to achieve such levels with cyberimplants (I doubt it), or another reason. Maybe a STAT has the same cost as Role Ability Rank and is mentioned somewhere?

Is there a way to increase a character's STATs with improvement points?

Answer (score 2):

### No, STATs can't be increased with improvement points

I received [an answer to this question from the official @RTalsorianGames account on Twitter](https://twitter.com/RTalsorianGames/status/1328400350072754177):

> You did not miss it. STATs are usually raised (temporarily) by drugs and more permanently by cyberware. 8 is roughly human maximum.

Comment: I add that surely I will house rule this to allow it in some circunstances with a cost as Role skill Rank, and double costs for 9 and 10 (1080 and 1200 IP)

Comment: I've edited out the unnecessary meta-commentary; you don't need to include things like "UPDATE" - especially when it's not an update to anything, just an answer to your question. In addition, images of text are inaccessible and generally unnecessary; instead, you should just quote the relevant text (in written form, not as an image) from the linked page in your answer, as I've done now.